# trouble building a rails form to return paramaters in desired format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

I'm trying to create a form where a user can add tickets to their accounts. The tickets are tiered (bronze, silver, gold) and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to get the form to output the data in the format I want.

```
    <%= form_for(@ticket) do |f|%>
         <%=f.label :tier_gold, "Gold" %>: <br>
         <%=f.number_field :tier%><br>
         <%=f.label :tier_silver, "Silver" %>:<br>
         <%=f.number_field :tier%><br>
         <%=f.label :tier_bronze, "Bronze" %>:<br>
         <%=f.number_field :tier%> <br><br>
    <%= f.submit "Get Tickets" %>
    <%end%>
```

this outputs the params `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "ticket"=>{"tier"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Get Tickets"}`

whereas I want the parameters to return something along the lines of  `{"authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "ticket"=>{"tier"=>{'gold => 1, 'silver => 3, 'bronze' => 5 }, "commit"=>"Get Tickets"}`

the Ticket model only contains the attributes user_id, raffle_id and tier.

Comment: Please post the model and controller code for @ticket. You are trying to get a hash of hashes as your return value. You are going to need to generate HTML along the lines of `<input name="ticket[tier][gold]" value="1"> ... <input name="ticket[tier][silver]" value="3">` Your form code will be a bit more complicated than what you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT*

I looked here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions
If you read that whole section you can see what I'm doing below. Here is a pure Rails solution that should work. I'll leave my HTML example for reference...

```
<%= form_for(@ticket) do |f|%>

  <%= fields_for(:tier)  do |fl|%>

    <%=fl.label :gold, "Gold" %>: 
    <br>
    <%=fl.number_field :gold %>
    <br>
     
    <%=fl.label :silver, "Silver" %>:
    <br>
    <%=fl.number_field :silver %>
    <br>
    
    <%=fl.label :bronze, "Bronze" %>:
    <br>
    <%=fl.number_field :bronze %>
    <br>

  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Since you didn't post your model code I'm not 100% sure this will work but let me know and we can tweak it as needed. This should give you the same result as my original answer below.

original answer:

You need to build the hash that you want returned using HTML format.

```
<label for="tier_gold"> Gold: </label><br>
<input type="number_field" name="ticket[tier][gold]">
<br>
<label for="tier_gold"> Silver: </label><br>
<input type="number_field" name="ticket[tier][silver]">
<br>
<label for="tier_gold"> Bronze: </label><br>
<input type="number_field" name="ticket[tier][bronze]">
```

This will return a hash in your params like:

```
"ticket"=>{"tier"=>{"gold" => 1, "silver" => 3, "bronze" => 5 }
```

You will need to make sure you whitelist this hash in your params with something like:

```
params.require(:ticket).permit(:tier => [:gold, :sliver, :bronze])
```

there is probably a way to make the standard `form_for` format spit out this HTML but I was unable to find it when working on similar code. If someone knows how to do that I'd be interested but it was easy just to build the HTML in my ERB file.

Comment: thanks a ton! i added attr_accessors to my tickets model (:bronze, :silver, :gold) and it started working, but your solution is a very clean way of handling it as well.

Comment: If you had a method that returned the various levels, say `ticket.levels` that returned an array of the levels i.e. `[:bronze, :silver, :gold]` you could condense it even more with a loop that just had one entry that would build each of the form elements in a loop. If you are only going to ever have those three I wouldn't bother. But if you foresaw a list that might expand you could use this idea and then any time you added to the array returned by the  `ticket.levels` method it would automatically generate the needed form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below to get the desired format for parameters -

```
<%= form_for(@ticket) do |f| %>
  <%=f.label :tier_gold, "Gold" %>: <br>
  <%=f.number_field :gold%><br>
  <%=f.label :tier_silver, "Silver" %>:<br>
  <%=f.number_field :silver %><br>
  <%=f.label :tier_bronze, "Bronze" %>:<br>
  <%=f.number_field :bronze %> <br><br>
  <%= f.submit "Get Tickets" %>
<% end %>
```

and add below code in your Ticket model

```
attr_accessor :gold, :silver, :bronze
```

Comment: 'undefined method `gold' for #<Ticket:0x00007f2760367188>'

the only attributes for the ticket class are user_id, raffle_id, and tier

Comment: I think then by adding attr_accessor, Ticket can have access to gold, silver and bronze too. `attr_accessor :gold, :silver, :bronze`